# How to create a dart package for importing local font files

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-pub

I'm using same local font files for more than one angular dart project, is there any way we can use dart's packaging system to create a separate package for importing forts instead of copying them from one `web` folder to another.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? If you have the font added to a package, you only need to add that package to `dependencies:` in `pubspec.yaml` and use `packages/my_font_package/my_font.ttf` paths to load the fonts.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/flutter/flutter_gallery_assets is such a package.

The Flutter asset docs also contain a section about asset packages https://flutter.io/assets-and-images/#from-packages

In the project that uses the fonts you register them using

```
flutter
  fonts: 
    - family: Raleway
      fonts: 
        - asset: packages/my_asset_package/fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf
```

like done in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/pubspec.yaml#L84-L157

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I have got one more question, Can it be configured to work with angular dart projects as well?

Comment: I think so, but fonts work a bit differently in the browser. You can use the same path to load the font as shown above in the `-asset: packages/my_asset_package/fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf` line, but Angular doesn't use `pubspec.yaml` to process assets or fonts, you need to add instructions to load fonts to `css` or `html` files.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had filtered for Flutter questions.